# Android Copying WebView to Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am working on a webview with local html file as source. 
I am trying to copy a Webview on to another webview.
If I do this.

```
WebView1.loadUrl(webView2.getUrl());
```

I works, but it is same as loading the webview again,which i dont want. If I do this

```
WebView1=WebView2;
```

It doesn't copy. The content of WebView1 doesn't change. Am I doing anything wrong.

Comment: Exactly, what do you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to avoid the loading time of the webview. So I show one page as my current view and keep the next page loaded in another webview, so whenever I want , will just copy temporary view on to my current view. Hope that make sense.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. But will this really reduce the time? It doesn't seems the right solution.

Comment: Can you suggest any other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to remove the current WebView from your Layout (by calling `removeView(WebView1)` on it's container) and then add the new WebView to it (`addView(WebView2)` on the same container). Obviously you'll have to take care that it gets inserted at the right place again. Easiest way would be to just wrap a `FrameLayout` around it and call said methods on it.

Can't promise you that this will work though, since I don't know how `WebView` behaves offscreen.